# Serve one flask app at root and another at a different path with apache2 and mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, debian-stretch

I am trying to serve one flask app directly at localhost, and another at localhost/menus.

When my apache configuration is like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost

# logs configuration -------------------------------------------------
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# front page ---------------------------------------------------------
WSGIDaemonProcess flask_ac user=#1000 group=#1000 threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /front /var/www/flask_ac/hookup.wsgi

<Directory /var/www/flask_ac>
    WSGIProcessGroup flask_ac
    WSGIApplicationGroup flask_ac
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# start menus --------------------------------------------------------
WSGIDaemonProcess menus user=#1000 group=#1000 threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /menus /var/www/flask_ac/projects/menus/hookup.wsgi

<Directory "/var/www/flask_ac/projects/menus/">
    WSGIProcessGroup menus
    WSGIApplicationGroup menus
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

It works fine, but it is serving the first app at localhost/front instead of just localhost.

If I change my first WSGIScriptAlias to:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flask_ac/hookup.wsgi
```

It will serve the first app correctly at localhost, but the second app at localhost/menus breaks, and returns not found.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882579/run-multiple-independent-flask-apps-in-ubuntu/) about a similar issue, but it doesn't address this directly, and I cant seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order such that the application for the sub URL is first.

```
WSGIScriptAlias /menus /var/www/flask_ac/projects/menus/hookup.wsgi

...

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flask_ac/hookup.wsgi
```

Documentation mentioning ordering at:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html#the-wsgiscriptalias-directive

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you for the solution, and the docs link for future reference.