# running multiple flask application using apache

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I have tried with all possible approaches on different websites. But have no luck.

Currently I am following - [Run multiple independent Flask apps in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882579/run-multiple-independent-flask-apps-in-ubuntu)

I have two flask application

```
/var/www/html/myapps/flaskapp2
/var/www/html/myapps/flaskapp
```

Both having python file and wsgi files.

/var/www/html/myapps/flaskapp2/flaskapp2.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/newflask")
def hello():
    return "Hello,welcome to flask website!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

/var/www/html/myapps/flaskapp2/flaskapp2.wsgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/html/myapps/flaskapp2/")

from flaskapp2 import app as application
```

and conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName http://IP
                ServerAlias IP
                ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com

                WSGIDaemonProcess app1 user=karim group=karim threads=5 python-home=/var/www/html/myapps/flaskapp:/home/k/projects_r/venv_3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
                WSGIScriptAlias /app1 /var/www/html/myapps/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/html/myapps/flaskapp>
                        WSGIApplicationGroup app1
                        WSGIProcessGroup app1
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>


                WSGIDaemonProcess app2 user=karim group=karim threads=5 python-home=/var/www/html/myapps/flaskapp2:/home/k/projects_r/venv_3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
                WSGIScriptAlias /app2 /var/www/html/myapps/flaskapp2/flaskapp2.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/html/myapps/flaskapp2>
                        WSGIApplicationGroup app2
                        WSGIProcessGroup app2
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to open

```
http://IP/myapps/flaskapp/flask
http://IP/myapps/flaskapp2/newflask
```

It gives me

> Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you
>   entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

**UPDATE 1**

only this app.conf  works at IP/flask

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName http://IP
                ServerAlias IP
                ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/html/flaskapp>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? We need more information than "have no luck" i'm afraid.

Comment: @Ewan: Yes, just updated

Comment: please send full traceback of your error

Comment: @nihal: Where do I get it

Comment: in python  error

Comment: What happens if you go to `http://IP`?

Comment: @Ewan: IT also gives same error message. But I have one more app `http://IP/flask` which works and print message

Comment: @Nihal: Can you tell me that path

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that you are using the wrong URLs. Your `WSGIScriptAlias` is set to listen on `/app1` and `/app2` respectively so I would first try accessing:

```
http://IP/app1
http://IP/app2
```

and check the [`WSGIScriptAlias` documentation](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIScriptAlias.html)

Comment: Thanks @Ewan: but this also ends up with same error message. I tried one you suggested and also `http://IP/app1/flask
http://IP/app2/newflask` as per the route I have given